# JSON can't get value [JS]

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem : I want to get the value of an object in JSON but i can't because the name of the object is just a number...
Take a look at my code:

```
const json = '{"7":"something", "hey":"something else"}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.7);
// expected output: "something"
// actual output : "Error: missing ) after argument list"
```

Comment: Just use the indexer `obj["7"]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets